# Charge pump design for pll

Tags: pll, charge-pump

I am designing this charge pump for a pll. But the control voltage always stays between 1.7 and 1.8V. Because of this the VCO after this always oscillates at its higher end of frequency. What parameter should I change to reduce this voltage to around 1V so that the control voltage is properly generated for corresponding vco oscillation frequency? Iref is 20uA.

[image: CP]
[image: Input]

Comment: You're designing this on the bench, or in a simulator? To implement on an IC? What inputs is your testbench putting on the Up and Down pins?

Comment: I am designing this on cadence TSMC180nm. The inputs are pulses coming from the phase detector.

Comment: If the inputs are not high-duty-cycle Down pulses, why do you expect the output to go low?

Comment: What behavior, what gain (amps/radian?) do you need? Are 10,000 nanosecond Up and Down pulses to be used? Or are 50 picosecond pulses to be used?

Comment: My reference frequency to pll is 25MHz. So as and when feedback pulse gets adjusted with reference the down pulse duty cycle changes

Comment: I thought since there is a current mirror the currents in all three branches must be equal. Is my interpretation right? Pls correct me if I am wrong

Comment: When the PLL is locked, the voltage at the input of the VCO is **not** determined by the charge pump. So trying to solve this in the chargepump is meaningless. If the PLL is really locked then the only thing which can be done is to change the VCO such that it outputs the desired frequency when it's input voltage is the voltage you want. But maybe the PLL is simply not locked.

Comment: When I simulated vco alone, a 1V at the control voltage was giving me the desired vco output frequency. So doesn't 1V be at the output of charge pump, which is the input to control voltage of vco, for the pll to get locked and hence vco can produce the required frequency? What else should I check to see whether the pll is locked or not?